# NHibernate Criteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc("Column.Property"))

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an OrderEntity that has a property OrderStatistics that has a property CreateDate. It looks like Order.OrderStatistics.CreateDate.

I will like to fetch all orders and sort them by CreateDate.

1. fetchQuery.UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc("OrderStatistics.CreateDate")) does not wokr
2. fetchQuery.UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc("CreatorName")) works

   How can I make 1 work ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fetchQuery
    .UnderlyingCriteria
    .CreateAlias("OrderStatistics", "stats")
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("stats.CreateDate"))
```

Or

```
OrderStatistic stats = null;
fetchQuery
    .CreateAlias(order => order.OrderStatistics, () => stats)
    .OrderBy(() => stats.CreateDate);
```

Comment: the first method helps me, I might have some more work to do in order to implement it because I receive a series of order columns like "name", "stats.currentdate", "contactName". Thank you for your answer !